# How to activate JOptionPane from another class?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, joptionpane

I have main class with a main GUI from where I want to activate and get values from a new class with a JOptionPane like the code below. Since I already have a main GUI window opened, how and where should I activate/call the class below and finally, how do I get the values from the JOptionPane? Help is preciated! Thanks!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class OptionPaneTest {

    JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
    JTextField field1 = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField field2 = new JTextField(10);
    myPanel.add(field1);
    myPanel.add(field2);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, myPanel);

}
```

Edit:

```
InputNewPerson nyPerson = new InputNewPerson();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, nyPerson);
String test = nyPerson.inputName.getText();
```

Comment: *"..like the code below. Since I already have a main GUI window opened.."*  That code does not compile.  How can it be 'open'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess looking at your question, you need something like this. I had made a small `JDialog`, where you will enter a `UserName` and `Answer`, this will then be passed to the original GUI to be shown in the respective fields, as you press the `SUBMIT JButton`.

Try your hands on this code and ask any question that may arise :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/*
 * This is the actual GUI class, which will get
 * values from the JDIalog class.
 */
public class GetDialogValues extends JFrame
{
    private JTextField userField;
    private JTextField questionField;

    public GetDialogValues()
    {
        super("JFRAME");
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGUI(GetDialogValues gdv)
    {       
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));

        JLabel userName = new JLabel("USERNAME : ");
        userField = new JTextField();
        JLabel questionLabel = new JLabel("Are you feeling GOOD ?");
        questionField = new JTextField();

        contentPane.add(userName);
        contentPane.add(userField);
        contentPane.add(questionLabel);
        contentPane.add(questionField);

        getContentPane().add(contentPane);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

        InputDialog id = new InputDialog(gdv, "Get INPUT : ", true);
    }

    public void setValues(final String username, final String answer)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                userField.setText(username);
                questionField.setText(answer);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                GetDialogValues gdv = new GetDialogValues();
                gdv.createAndDisplayGUI(gdv);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}

class InputDialog extends JDialog
{
    private GetDialogValues gdv;
    private JTextField usernameField;
    private JTextField questionField;
    private JButton submitButton;
    private ActionListener actionButton = new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            if (usernameField.getDocument().getLength() > 0
                && questionField.getDocument().getLength() > 0)
            {
                gdv.setValues(usernameField.getText().trim()
                    , questionField.getText().trim());
                dispose();
            }
            else if (usernameField.getDocument().getLength() == 0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter USERNAME."
                    , "Invalid USERNAME : ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            else if (questionField.getDocument().getLength() == 0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Answer the question"
                    , "Invalid ANSWER : ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    };

    public InputDialog(GetDialogValues gdv, String title, boolean isModal)
    {
        this.gdv = gdv;
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setModal(isModal);
        setTitle(title);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("Enter USERNAME : ");
        usernameField = new JTextField();
        JLabel questionLabel = new JLabel("How are you feeling ?");
        questionField = new JTextField();

        panel.add(usernameLabel);
        panel.add(usernameField);
        panel.add(questionLabel);
        panel.add(questionField);

        submitButton = new JButton("SUBMIT");
        submitButton.addActionListener(actionButton);

        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(submitButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Welcome and Keep Smiling :-) . If you got any doubt, do ask me :-)

Answer (score 2):

`JOPtionPane` provides a number of [preset dialog types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features) that can be used. However, when you are trying to do something that does not fit the mold of one of those types, it is best to create your own dialog by making a sub-class of [`JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html). Doing this will give you full control over how the controls are laid out and ability to respond to button clicks as you want. You will want to add an `ActionListener` for the OK button. Then, in that callback, you can extract the values from the text fields.

The process of creating a custom dialog should be very similar to how you created the main window for your GUI. Except, instead of extending `JFrame`, you should extend `JDialog`. Here is a very basic [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Createsimpleaboutdialog.htm). In the example, the `ActionListener` just closes the dialog. You will want to add more code that extracts the values from the text fields and provides them to where they are needed in the rest of your code.

Comment: I was trying to do this since there are no option with multipli textfields

Comment: Some help is preciated since I don't know how to do?

Comment: I have made some progress, but I would preciate some help how to implement the actionlistener and get the values that i enter?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: I added some more detail and provided an example.

Comment: And I added some more to my question. I use the extends JDialog and I get the new dialog on my screen, but then I thought I could get the values like I wrote in the third line, but this doesn't work?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: You don't want to use `showMessageDialog()`, it generates a preset dialog. You want to call `setVisible(true)` on your dialog object in order to show it. Also, your edit is not very helpful as you do not show what `InputNewPerson` is. I have to assume it is the class you used to extend `JDialog`.

Comment: Yes the InputNewPerson is the class that I extend the JDialog. Hmm, if Iäm going to use the setVisible(true), then I guess I have to make an instance of this new window? And use setVisible(true) when I want to use it?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: Dialogs are generally short lived, so there is no reason to have an instance around when it is not being used. Make the instance when you need it, show it, close it, and then let it be garbage collected.